# Where does $\tan 2a = \frac{B}{A - C}$ come from?

Tags: waves, reference-frames, polarization

I was reading about elliptical polarisation and stumbled across an equation involving the rotation angle of the ellipse. It has the form

$$\tan(2a) = \frac{B}{A - C}$$

where $B$, $A$ and $C$ are the coefficients of the GENERAL equation

$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

What is the physical intuition behind this trigonometric formula? Does it involve coordinate transformation or a change in reference frame?

Comment: I think this is more of a maths question than a physics question. You might consider asking on the [Maths SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But doesn't the question fall into the category of "Mathematics in the context of physics", which is in accordance with the help centre's permitted question types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a coordinate system that the ellipse is not rotated; the axis of the ellipse match the axis of the coordinate system, the $xy$ term does not exist. Now to find the angle of rotation we need to find the relation between the $x$, $y$ with the $x'$ and $y'$, where the former are the coordinates of rotated ellipse and the later are in fixed system:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\
y\\
\end{array} \right) = \underbrace{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta\\
\end{array} \right)}_{\text{Rotation matrix}}\left( \begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y'\\
\end{array} \right) $$

Now you need to substitute $x$ and $y$ with $x'$ and $y'$ in the equation of ellipse, then equate the coefficient of $x'y'$ term to zero :

$$2A\sin\theta\cos\theta-2C\sin\theta\cos\theta+B(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=0\\
\Rightarrow (A-C)\sin2\theta+B\cos2\theta=0\\
\Rightarrow \tan2\theta=\Big|\frac{B}{A-C}\Big|$$

There is an ambiguity in the sign of $\theta$ which depends on your choice of rotation matrix, however, the absolute value remains the same.